# I keep getting uninitialized constant ID3 (NameError)

Tags: ruby

All I want to do is put csv files into this program with rules and get a yes or no answer and I keep getting unitilized constants even though I am placing ID3.new getting assigned  ...  please advise    this has been extremely frustrating all day

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'ai4r'
require 'csv'


data_set = []

  CSV.open('id5.csv', 'r') do |row|
    data_set << row
  end
  data_labels = data_set.shift

  id3 = ID3.new(data_set, data_labels)




id3.get_rules
     if age_range=='<30' then marketing_target='Y'
          elsif age_range=='[30-50)' and city=='Chicago' then marketing_target='Y'
          elsif age_range=='[30-50)' and city=='New York' then marketing_target='N'
          elsif age_range=='[50-80]' then marketing_target='N'
          elsif age_range=='>80' then marketing_target='Y'
          else raise 'There was not enough information during training to do a proper induction for this data element' end

  puts id3.eval(['New York', '<30', 'M'])
    # =>  'Y'
```

Comment: What provides the `ID3` class? Do you have custom code or is it a rubygem? You haven't `require`'d anything related to id3 and that would appear to be your issue.

Comment: You can create an ID3 Decision tree to do the dirty job for you:,  it is saying in ai4R.com to create an ID3 decision tree...   this is where I am confused at the incomplete code ...

Comment: Can you post a link to that, or edit above to include exactly the partial code they show? `ID3` will have to be defined as a module or class.

Comment: http://www.ai4r.org/machineLearning.html#mach-eval

Comment: Okay, so it appears the `ID3` class is defined in a submodule of `Ai4r`.  Try doing that as `id3 = Ai4r::Classifiers::ID3.new(data_set, data_labels)` to fully qualify the module that class resides in.

Comment: data_set = [] CSV::Reader.parse('id3.csv', 'r') do |row|
    data_set << row
  end
  data_labels = data_set.shift  * saying now that this is unitialized?

Comment: @user3565781 it looks like after edits, you are arriving to a new issue. Please edit the question title/body to reflect the new issue. Edit the code to reflect the changes you have made.